# SQL query output is correct, but the program in php is written is unable to show the results

Tags: php, mysql

Here in the below mentioned program, I have written an SQL query, which displays the amount remaining. I have checked the query, it is working correctly. 
I think there's an issue with php program written, I am unable to find the problem.

Thanks for reading my problem.

```
<?php
    $sql2 = "SELECT AMOUNT_REMAINAING from MAIN_TABLE ORDER BY AMOUNT_REMAINAING DESC LIMIT 1";
    $query2 = $dbh -> prepare($sql2);
    $query2->execute();
    $results2=$query2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>

 <div class="stat-panel-number h1 "><?php echo htmlentities($results2[0]); ?></div>
 <div class="stat-panel-title text-uppercase">Budget Remaining</div>

<a href="manage-vehicles.php" class="block-anchor panel-footer text-center">Full Detail &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

**EDIT 1:**

My Table 
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
After solution by Tim Biegeleisen, the result is same 
[image]

With Paul Coldrey's solution this is the result

[image]

**EDIT 3:**
Thats what I am getting by print_r(results2);

[image]

Comment: what result are you seeing? fetchAll will be returning an array

Comment: Note that remaining and remainaing are not the same thing.

Comment: @Strawberry I got to know earlier that I have misspelt remaining. Therefore I edited my sql query, but it didn't solve my issue

Comment: what do you see if you add print_r(results2) to your code?

Comment: @PaulColdrey I have edited the question.

Comment: what you want as a output also show us print_r(results2);
and object are access via : -> (operator)

-> is used to call a method on the object of a class

Comment: oops, typo! It was meant to be print_r($results2). See my updated answer - I think it should solve your problem

Comment: Still, you might want to fix your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since fetchAll returns an array I would expect you need a [0] to get the first row. Then you will need another [0] to get the first column. Also the FETCH_OBJ will give you back an object but you really just want the value. Hence I think you want:

```
<?php
    $sql2 = "SELECT AMOUNT_REMAINAING from MAIN_TABLE ORDER BY AMOUNT_REMAINAING DESC LIMIT 1 ";
    $query2 = $dbh -> prepare($sql2);
    $query2->execute();
    $results2=$query2->fetchAll()[0][0];
?>
```

you can also explicitly select only the first column like this:

```
$query2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

And then you would need to choose the first row with a [0], so the line would be

```
$results2=$query2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fetchAll` function will return an *array* of all results for the single `AMOUNT_REAMINING` column which you selected.  Since you also added `LIMIT 1`, this array should only have (at most) one item.  So, just access that first item:

```
$results2[0]
```

Your updated HTML code:

```
<div class="stat-panel-number h1 "><?php echo htmlentities($results2[0]); ?></div>
<div class="stat-panel-title text-uppercase">Budget Remaining</div>
```